# apache reverse proxy 404 image error

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, apache-2.4

I have some error with my apache reverse proxy. Currently I am doing reverse proxy to 4 websites.

- 1.1.1.1/a
- 1.1.1.2/b
- 1.1.1.3/c
- 1.1.1.4/d

I am having no problem when reverse proxy to a and b website. Image are good and no problem.

However, when comes to c and d website. Image are not getting loaded.In my access_log , here are the logs.

```
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /whatshot_v3/images/promo/img_samplePromo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/menu/faq_butt_03.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/banner/text_planprice.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/banner/text_services.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/banner/text_account.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/shortcut/bann_store.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/shortcut/bann_rewards.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/shortcut/bann_idd.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/footer/img_customerService.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/footer/icon_fb.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/footer/icon_tw.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/footer/icon_rss.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
- - [08/May/2014:10:40:36 +0800] "GET /images_v3/footer/icon_share.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
```

Accessing from the apache reverse proxy server itself have no problem. When accessing from outside, the problem occur.

I have try directly typing the url in another machine and the image are loaded.

```
1.1.1.1 - - [08/May/2014:10:19:00 +0800] "GET **/d/images_v3/footer/icon_share.png** HTTP/1.1" 200 869 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
1.1.1.1 - - [08/May/2014:10:18:24 +0800] "GET **/images_v3/footer/icon_share.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1245** "htt://1.2.3.4/digi/landing.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
```

As you can see the link in the first one is working. The one in the second one is not.

When I request the webpage normally, it will request the second link and it will cause 404 error as cannot find the path.

If i type directly the first link , the image was found.

I notice that c and d website are redirected when type the link.And this is the cause of the problem.

```
1.1.1.3/c --> 1.1.1.3/c/index_other.html 
1.1.1.4/d --> 1.1.1.4/d/landing.do
```

Here is my apache reverse proxy configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    #DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    #ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/arp_error_log
    CustomLog logs/arp_access_log common

    ProxyRequests Off

        <Location /a>
                ProxyPass http://1.1.1.1/a
                ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.1/a
        </Location>

        <Location /b>
                ProxyPass http://1.1.1.2/b
                ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.2/b  
        </Location>

        <Location /c>
                ProxyPass http://1.1.1.3/index_other.html
                ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.3/index_other.html
        </Location>

        <Location /d>
            ProxyPass http://1.1.1.4:8080
            ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.4:8080
         </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

So , how do i solve this? I have been researching mod_rewrite and mod_proxy_html , but no luck in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use seperate Location containers for the images.

I am not testing this but this should be more or less it.

For /c:

```
    <Location /c/images_v3>
            ProxyPass http://1.1.1.3/images_v3
            ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.3/images_v3
    </Location>

    <Location /c>
            ProxyPass http://1.1.1.3/index_other.html
            ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.3/index_other.html
    </Location>
```

For /d I am not quite sure what is happenign, maybe there is a redirect on 1.1.1.4:8080 that redericts everything to /landing.do ? In this case the following would not help:

```
    <Location /d/images_v3>
        ProxyPass http://1.1.1.4:8080/images_v3
        ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.4:8080/images_v3
     </Location>

    <Location /d>
        ProxyPass http://1.1.1.4:8080
        ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.4:8080
     </Location>
```